# How to resolve utf-8 error when using odo function ? OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) Could not decode to UTF-8 column

Tags: python, python-2.7, blaze, odo, sqlalchemy-continuum

I am new to odo. I have a simple function for migrating databases:

```
from blaze import Data, odo, like

def migrate(source, target, table_names=None):
    src_db = Data(source)
    tbl_names = (src_db.fields, table_names)[table_names is not None]
    for tbl in tbl_names:
        display("Migrating Tablename ::" + tbl)
        odo?
        odo('{0}::{1}'.format(source, tbl), '{0}::{1}'.format(target, tbl))

migrate(url_config, url_config_bcp)
```

On running this on a SQLite database.

```
 url_config = 'sqlite:///DB_CONFIG.db'
 url_config_bcp = 'sqlite:///DB_CONFIG_BCP.db'
 migrate(url_config, url_config_bcp)
```

I get following error.

How can I resolve this ?

> OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) Could not decode to UTF-8
>   column 'V_WIMS_WELLS$COMMENTS' with text '  29/12/2013 : SAP issue
>   related , WO# was closed but still apprear in WIMS for confirmation .
>
> WPH-41 Cut Surface CSG 9-5/8¿ on b

P.S :- I am aware that we can set textfactory expilicitly in sqlalchemy

```
db = create_engine('sqlite:///{0}'.format(sqlite_name))
conn = db.raw_connection()
conn.connection.text_factory = str
```

I don't know how to fix it within odo function

#

A second attempt at writing function by passing metadata explicitly results in following error

```
def migrate(source, target, table_names=None):
    src_db = Data(source)
    engine = sa.create_engine(source)
    conn = engine.raw_connection()
    conn.connection.text_factory = str
    metadata = sa.MetaData()
    metadata.bind = engine

    tbl_names = (src_db.fields, table_names)[table_names is not None]

    for tbl in tbl_names:
        display("Migrating Tablename ::" + tbl)
        odo(sa.Table(tbl, metadata), '{0}::{1}'.format(target, tbl))
```

ERROR:-

```
---> 26 migrate(url_config, url_config_bcp)

<ipython-input-21-146061c63d09> in migrate(source, target, table_names)
     21     for tbl in tbl_names:
     22         display("Migrating Tablename ::" + tbl)
---> 23         odo(sa.Table(tbl, metadata), '{0}::{1}'.format(target, tbl))

     25 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\odo.pyc in odo(source, target, **kwargs)
     89     odo.append.append      - Add things onto existing things
     90     """
---> 91     return into(target, source, **kwargs)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    162             self._cache[types] = func
    163         try:
--> 164             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    165 
    166         except MDNotImplementedError:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\into.pyc in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     41             raise TypeError('dshape argument is not an instance of DataShape')
     42         kwargs['dshape'] = dshape
---> 43         return f(*args, **kwargs)
     44     return wrapped
     45 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\into.pyc in into_string(uri, b, dshape, **kwargs)
    141 
    142     a = resource(uri, dshape=resource_ds, expected_dshape=dshape, **kwargs)
--> 143     return into(a, b, dshape=dshape, **kwargs)
    144 
    145 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    162             self._cache[types] = func
    163         try:
--> 164             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    165 
    166         except MDNotImplementedError:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\into.pyc in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     41             raise TypeError('dshape argument is not an instance of DataShape')
     42         kwargs['dshape'] = dshape
---> 43         return f(*args, **kwargs)
     44     return wrapped
     45 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\into.pyc in into_object(target, source, dshape, **kwargs)
    129         if dshape is None:
    130             dshape = discover(source)
--> 131     return append(target, source, dshape=dshape, **kwargs)
    132 
    133 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    162             self._cache[types] = func
    163         try:
--> 164             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    165 
    166         except MDNotImplementedError:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\backends\sql.pyc in append_table_to_sql_Table(t, o, **kwargs)
    460 def append_table_to_sql_Table(t, o, **kwargs):
    461     s = sa.select([o])
--> 462     return append(t, s, **kwargs)
    463 
    464 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    162             self._cache[types] = func
    163         try:
--> 164             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    165 
    166         except MDNotImplementedError:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\backends\sql.pyc in append_select_statement_to_sql_Table(t, o, bind, **kwargs)
    470         return append(
    471             t,
--> 472             convert(Iterator, o, bind=bind, **kwargs),
    473             bind=bind,
    474             **kwargs

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\core.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     42 
     43     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
---> 44         return _transform(self.graph, *args, **kwargs)
     45 
     46 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\core.pyc in _transform(graph, target, source, excluded_edges, ooc_types, **kwargs)
     58     try:
     59         for (A, B, f) in pth:
---> 60             x = f(x, excluded_edges=excluded_edges, **kwargs)
     61         return x
     62     except NotImplementedError as e:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\backends\sql.pyc in select_or_selectable_to_frame(el, bind, **kwargs)
    598 @convert.register(pd.DataFrame, (sa.sql.Select, sa.sql.Selectable), cost=200.0)
    599 def select_or_selectable_to_frame(el, bind=None, **kwargs):
--> 600     columns, rows = batch(el, bind=bind)
    601     row = next(rows, None)
    602     if row is None:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\backends\sql.pyc in batch(sel, chunksize, bind)
    136                     return
    137     terator = rowterator(sel)
--> 138     return next(terator), concat(terator)
    139 
    140 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\odo\backends\sql.pyc in rowterator(sel, chunksize)
    126     def rowterator(sel, chunksize=chunksize):
    127         with getbind(sel, bind).connect() as conn:
--> 128             result = conn.execute(sel)
    129             yield result.keys()
    130 

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.pyc in execute(self, object, *multiparams, **params)
    912                 type(object))
    913         else:
--> 914             return meth(self, multiparams, params)
    915 
    916     def _execute_function(self, func, multiparams, params):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.pyc in _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params)
    321 
    322     def _execute_on_connection(self, connection, multiparams, params):
--> 323         return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
    324 
    325     def unique_params(self, *optionaldict, **kwargs):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.pyc in _execute_clauseelement(self, elem, multiparams, params)
   1008             compiled_sql,
   1009             distilled_params,
-> 1010             compiled_sql, distilled_params
   1011         )
   1012         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.pyc in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1144                 parameters,
   1145                 cursor,
-> 1146                 context)
   1147 
   1148         if self._has_events or self.engine._has_events:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.pyc in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1339                 util.raise_from_cause(
   1340                     sqlalchemy_exception,
-> 1341                     exc_info
   1342                 )
   1343             else:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.pyc in raise_from_cause(exception, exc_info)
    198             exc_info = sys.exc_info()
    199         exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb = exc_info
--> 200         reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
    201 
    202 if py3k:

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.pyc in _execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, *args)
   1137                         statement,
   1138                         parameters,
-> 1139                         context)
   1140         except Exception as e:
   1141             self._handle_dbapi_exception(

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.pyc in do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context)
    448 
    449     def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
--> 450         cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    451 
    452     def do_execute_no_params(self, cursor, statement, context=None):

OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "FROM": syntax error [SQL: u'SELECT  \nFROM "C_PATTERN"']
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that worked for me while in pandas (which will hopefully carry over into odo) was to convert each column via df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.encode('utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `encoding` argument while migrating in `odo`

```
odo(source, target, encoding='cp1252')
```

Comment: I have tried passing  encoding as 'cp1252' and 'latin1' . I get following errors-

ValueError: Unsupported string encoding u'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'